# django redirect to different view/page if permission denied

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-permissions

Hej!

I have a view where contact details are rendered. The goal is to have some users who are allowed to see all details ('A') and some who only can see for example the name ('B').
Therefore I have two serializers in my model and two views (one for each serializer). The users are divided in two groups.

The `@user_passes_test` does work so only the one in group 'A' are able to get into the view with the details.

I want the ones which are in group 'B' to be redirected automatically to the view/page where the details are minimized.

Any idea how to achieve that?

I've got:

```
# views.py
def contacts_check(user):
   return user.groups.filter(name="Contacts = True").exists()


@login_required
@user_passes_test(contacts_check)
def contacts(request):
   .
   .
   .


@login_required
def contacts_small(request):
   .
   .
   .
```

```
# urls.py


app_name = "app"
urlpatterns = [
    path("contacts", contacts, name="contacts"),
    path("contacts2", contacts_small, name='contacts2')
]
```

I tried:

```
@user_passes_test(contacts_check, login_url='contacts')
```

but both user groups are directed to the url 'contacts' with the full view. ('B' gets an error that the user has no access). Same when login_url='contacts2'.

I also tried:

```
def sees_contacts(self):
   if str(self.user.groups.filter) == 'Contacts = True':
       return True
   else:
       return False
con_login_required = user_passes_test(lambda u: True if u.sees_individuals else False, login_url='individuals2')


def contacts_login_required(view_func):
   decorated_view_func = login_required(con_login_required(view_func), login_url='contacts2')
   return decorated_view_func
```

not filtering/not redirection properly.

```
# views.py 
def contacts_check(user):
   return user.groups.filter(name="Contacts= True").exists()


def contacts_view(request):
   if contacts_check():
       return search_contacts(request)
   return search_contacts_small(request)

@login_required
def search_contacts(request):
   ....


@login_required
def search_contacts_small(request):
   ....
```

Does anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In urls.py just use one path

```
path("contacts/", contacts_view, name="contacts-view"),
```

then in the method

```
def contacts_view(request):
    if sees_contacts():
        return contacts(request)
    return contacts_small(request)
```

This will help keep url patterns less confusing for you and users and allow you to easily separate the views.

Comment: this looks perfect! I created the method you suggested but now get an error: `Reverse for 'contacts' not found. 'contacts' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`  Do you know whats going wrong?

Comment: you need to reverse for "contacts-view" if you've used my code

Comment: Than the error 'contacts_check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'' 
Do I have to change my check in order to not get it through a decorator, but inside the method?

Comment: If the () of contacts_check(): are deleted there is no longer an error, but won't filter either.

Comment: It really depends where you're storing each of your methods, it's not clear what classes have what methods from what you've shown. I think best would be passing the request and then using request.user should work

Comment: all my views-methods are in the views.py together with your `def contacts_view(request):` and my check method. Therefore I now have 4 methods: 2 'views', the check-method and yours.
Where should I use request.user? 
And I don't work with class based views, so there are no classes in those files. Does that help?

Comment: how do I reverse my 'contact-view'? I can't find a solution for this. 
Or pass my request? Still can't get it working :/

Comment: when you got the error at the top of this comments section you called reverse to get that error, right? you return the expected view like: return redirect(reverse('contacts-view')). I imagine this is how you are attempting to get to the contacts view. When you 'pass an argument' it refers to the arguments in brackets of a method that need to be passed to it for it to work